# set custom limit for pagination magento2

Tags: magento2, collection, custom, pagination

how can i set the custom limit for pager. this is adding the limit in page and page is showing but the dropdown on limit is not showing on page how to dropdown of limit on Custom Collection.

`->setAvailableLimit(array(1=>1,2=>2,3=>3))`

i tried this but not working

```
public function getAvailableLimit()
    {
        return array(1=>1,2=>2,3=>3);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after spending many of hours i checked this is a css by default

```
.limiter {
    display: none;
}
```

so i have to overwrite in my module

```
.news-index-index .limiter {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to add pagination on my custom page , but the count is not working as expected , $pager->setLimit(36), how can I set it as dynamic which we are filling in admin??

Comment: @supriyamishra can you add question with your code so i can look at that

Comment: Sure , I am adding

Comment: @Qaiser Satti    kindly look into this problem http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/155959/pagination-limit-need-to-make-dynamic