# Pagination Limit Need to make dynamic

Tags: magento2, pagination

I am adding pagination block to my custom shop by brand module, here is Block file

```
<?php
namespace PinkBlue\ShopByBrand\Block;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status;

class View extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_defaultToolbarBlock = 'Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar';
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context
     */
    protected $httpContext;
    /**
     * Catalog product visibility
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility
     */
    protected $_catalogProductVisibility;

    /**
     * Product collection factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_productCollectionFactory;
    protected $_productCollection;
    /**
     * Image helper
     *
     * @var Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image
     */
    protected $_imageHelper;
     /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart
     */
    protected $_cartHelper;

    protected $_brandFactory;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility $catalogProductVisibility,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext,
        \PinkBlue\ShopByBrand\Model\BrandFactory $brandFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->_catalogProductVisibility = $catalogProductVisibility;
        $this->httpContext = $httpContext;
        $this->_imageHelper = $context->getImageHelper();
        $this->_brandFactory = $brandFactory;
        $this->_cartHelper = $context->getCartHelper();
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $data
        );
    $this->setCollection($this->getProductCollection());
    }
     public function getAddToCartUrl($product, $additional = [])
    {
            return $this->_cartHelper->getAddUrl($product, $additional);
    }



    public function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        $brand = $this->getBrand();
        $brand_url = ($brand->getUrlKey())?
            $this->getUrl('brand').$brand->getUrlKey():
            $this->getUrl('brand/view/',array('id'=>$brand->getId()));
        $this->pageConfig->addRemotePageAsset(
            $brand_url,
            'canonical',
            ['attributes' => ['rel' => 'canonical']]
        );
        //sup code for pagination
        if ($this->getCollection()) {
            $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                'Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager',
                'reward.history.pager');
            $pager->setLimit(36)
            ->setShowAmounts(false)
            ->setCollection($this->getCollection());
        $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
        $this->getCollection()->load();
        }
        //Sup code ends
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPagerHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
    }

    public function getBrand(){
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        if ($id) {
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $model = $objectManager->create('PinkBlue\ShopByBrand\Model\Items');
            $model->load($id);
            return $model;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function getProductCollection()
    {
        if($this->_productCollection===NULL) {
            $brand = $this->getBrand();
            $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name');
            $collection->addStoreFilter()->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', $brand->getAttributeId());

            $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
            $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array('neq' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE));
            $this->_productCollection = $collection;
        }
        return $this->_productCollection;
    }

    public function imageHelperObj(){
        return $this->_imageHelper;
    }

    public function getProductPricetoHtml(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
        $priceType = null
    ) {
        $priceRender = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('product.price.render.default');
        $price = '';
        if ($priceRender) {
            $price = $priceRender->render(
                \Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice::PRICE_CODE,
                $product
            );
        }
        return $price;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve list toolbar HTML
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getToolbarHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('toolbar');
    }
    /**
     * Retrieve additional blocks html
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAdditionalHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('additional');
    }
    /**
     * Retrieve Toolbar block
     *
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
     */
    public function getToolbarBlock()
    {
        $blockName = $this->getToolbarBlockName();
        if ($blockName) {
            $block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock($blockName);
            if ($block) {
                return $block;
            }
        }
        $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock($this->_defaultToolbarBlock, uniqid(microtime()));
        return $block;
    }
    /**
     * Retrieve current view mode
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMode()
    {
        return $this->getChildBlock('toolbar')->getCurrentMode();
    }
    /**
     * Need use as _prepareLayout - but problem in declaring collection from
     * another block (was problem with search result)
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $toolbar = $this->getToolbarBlock();

        // called prepare sortable parameters
        $collection = $this->getProductCollection();

        // use sortable parameters
        $orders = $this->getAvailableOrders();
        if ($orders) {
            $toolbar->setAvailableOrders($orders);
        }
        $sort = $this->getSortBy();
        if ($sort) {
            $toolbar->setDefaultOrder($sort);
        }
        $dir = $this->getDefaultDirection();
        if ($dir) {
            $toolbar->setDefaultDirection($dir);
        }
        $modes = $this->getModes();
        if ($modes) {
            $toolbar->setModes($modes);
        }

        // set collection to toolbar and apply sort
        $toolbar->setCollection($collection);
        $this->setChild('toolbar', $toolbar);
        $this->getProductCollection()->load();
        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }
}
```

I want to make the limit dynamic 
but here i have set it as

```
 $pager->setLimit(36)
```

How Can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

    protected $context;
    protected $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context, \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig) {
        $this->context = $context;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareLayout() {

        parent::_prepareLayout();

        $limit = $this->context->getRequest()->getParam('limit');
        $limit = addslashes(strip_tags($limit));

        $pagingVal = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('<value path>', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);  // 36

        $pagingLimit = (isset($limit) && !empty($limit)) ? $limit : $pagingVal;

        ->setLimit($pagingLimit) // Change Variable in your query

        return $this;
   }
}
```

Comment: $pagingLimit = (isset($limit) && !empty($limit)) ? $limit : <Your Value>;  I want this <your value > programatically taken from admin config.

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: How can I make it so that user can change from frontend - want to add block Show   per page ?

Comment: `->setAvailableLimit(array(5 => 5, 10 => 10, 15 => 15, 20 => 20, 25 => 25))->setShowPerPage(true)->setLimit(`

Comment: my pagination is not showing at default position, which block i should render in template.